# Find a concrete example of non-principality of the codifferent and different ideal of a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, extension-field

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ be an (algebraic) number field, $f(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ and $O_K$ be its ring of integers. It's known that, if $K$ is [monogenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_field), i.e. $O_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ (ring extension) with some $\alpha \in K$, then the codifferent (fractional) ideal $O^\vee_K = [f'(\alpha)]^{-1} O_K$. In the other words, consider all of its respective integral ideals, which are achieved by suitably *scaling* $O^\vee_K$, $O_K$ is one of them and is principal, hence the rest of them is principal. Now we call that **$O^\vee_K$ is principal**. In general, it's equivalent to that the different (integral) ideal **$(O^\vee_K)^{-1}$ is principal**.

On the other hand, it's also known that, there is infinitely many $K$ that is **not monogenic**. $K = \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ ($\beta$ is the real root of $X^3-X^2-2X-8$) is Dedekind's example. Despite that, it's not clear whether $O^\vee_K$ and $(O^\vee_K)^{-1}$ are principal or not. For this example, we have $O_K = \mathbb{Z} \left [ \beta, \frac{\beta+\beta^2}{2} \right ]$ and $O^\vee_K = \frac{207-18\beta-20\beta^2}{503}O_K$ is principal, leading to that $(O^\vee_K)^{-1} = (25+14\beta+8\beta^2)O_K$ is principal.

My curiosity makes me target the exhaustion of cases. Particularly, I want to find a $K$ that is **not monogenic** and has $O^\vee_K$, $(O^\vee_K)^{-1}$ be **not principal**. That is my question.

Comment: Your terminology "respectively principal" is unusual.  A fractional ideal is principal if and only if its inverse is, so why not just talk about these fractional ideals not being principal?

Comment: @KCd Sorry for the ad-hoc terminology. I did point out that they are equivalent.

Comment: If "respectively principal" and "actually principal" both mean "principal" then don't use the words "actually" or "respectively" anywhere, since all they do is make your writing confusing. If you are looking for an example of a number field whose different ideal is not principal (which is what the subject line sounds like), then in your post just ask for that.

Comment: @KCd I just want to separate the principality of fractional and integral ideals for anyone not familiar with the area. I've fixed the question. By the way, I make the wrong choice here: it seems that who reads my question already knows about all this stuff, just asking the question still works.

Comment: See the end of Example 4.15 at http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf. Replacing 5 and 7 there (as factors of $175 = 5^2 \cdot 7$) with other primes fitting conditions that let all the calculations there go through, you can create more examples.